# How to use fragments in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to pass the listener parameter to the fragment but I am getting the error. I have declared the editTextAge globally

```
editTextAge.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            DlgNumberPickerFragm newFragment = new DlgNumberPickerFragm();

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DlgNumberPickerFragm.dlgAgePicker(R.string.app_name, R.drawable.imgdialogbox, "\t\t\tSelect Age", AdptCardUI.this).show(this.newFragment.getFragmentManager(), "first");
            }
        });    
at AdptCardUI.this).show(this.newFragment.getFragmentManager(), "first");
            }
        });
```

I have tried

```
this).show(this.getFragmentManager();

this).show(this.getChildFragmentManager();

this).show(this.newFragment.getFragmentManager();

AdptCardUI.this).show(this.newFragment.getFragmentManager();
```

But I didn't get any answer.

Comment: please anyone help me to solver this issue

Comment: what error u get pls tell

Comment: I cant access the fragmentManager in while passing the parameter to fragment class.. it showing error..
        editTextAge.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DlgNumberPickerFragm.dlgAgePicker(R.string.app_name, R.drawable.imgdialogbox, "\t\t\tSelect Age", AdptCardUI.this).show(, "first");

            }

        });

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution thank you...

```
editTextAge.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            FragmentManager fm=((Activity)mContext).getFragmentManager();
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DlgNumberPickerFragm.dlgAgePicker(R.string.app_name, R.drawable.imgdialogbox, "\t\t\tSelect Age", AdptCardUI.this).show(fm, "first");

            }

        });
```